# How to Implement Selenium WebDriver with PhantomJS and Can we Use Sikuli with PhantomJS?

Tags: java, automation, phantomjs, sikuli

I am trying to use following code for running my script in headless browser in PhantomJS.

```
public void setUp() throws Exception{
       Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
       ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
       ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);  
       ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(
               PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
               "/Users/kamal.kumar/Desktop/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs.exe"
           );
      // System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drivers/geckodriver");
       isr=new Scanner(System.in);
       ReadExcelFile ob=new ReadExcelFile();
       ArrayList<String> data=ob.extractData();

      // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver");
       //driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver=new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
       /*
       for(String i:data)
           System.out.println(i);
       */
       userName=data.get(0);
       password=data.get(1);
       approverName=data.get(2);
       activityCode=data.get(3);

       baseUrl="http://"+userName+":"+password+"@sparshv2/";

       driver.get(baseUrl);
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
```

I am getting error when i am trying to run it:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/kamal.kumar/Desktop/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs.exe
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS(PhantomJSDriverService.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
    at TimeSheetAutomation.setUp(TimeSheetAutomation.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TimeSheetAutomation.tearDown(TimeSheetAutomation.java:471)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Or i am using Sikuli which is working fine with selenium. But now because i want to shift from selenium to PhantomJS so can we Use Sikuli with PhantomJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with switch window concept, first save the existence of parent window then trace the existence of child window. Then switch to child window and do all the operations on child window, then switch back to parent window.

```
Code:

   String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
            String subWindowHandler = null;

            Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
            Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
            }
            driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); 

*****perform operations on child window******************

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
```

I hope this will solve your problem